# scheduler for a database

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to write a program in visual studio 2010 which will run a function once every 10pm. The function is to basically an insertion to the database. What would be the most easiest way of writing this? I am pretty sure I don't need ASP.NET as it is an overkill for such problem...

I am just confused on what project should I start

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to create a Console Application project and use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to schedule it to run according to whatever schedule you'd like.

Comment: I was thinking of using a console application as well, but how do you code this?

Comment: You write your console application (in visual studio, new project, console application) to do your task exactly once. Then you set up Windows Task Scheduler as described to run your executable at 10pm every day.

Comment: how do I go into converting my console application to an executable?

Comment: I recommend following this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has the SQL Server Agent built in. You can use it to schedule such a command to run whenever you like.

Comment: +1 Just create the function/stored procedure and have your DBA setup a job to execute it every 10PM. The simplest, fastest way to do it.